# CSS - Classes, IDs, and Elements: What's the Difference?

Tags: html, css, class

In CSS there are a few ways of addressing different elements. (I am going do use `div` elements in the following example.)

Classes - `div.main {`

IDs - `#id-name {`

Element - `div {`

Let's say I'm making a simple animation, and I want to make a `p` element spin.

```css
p {
  text-align:center;
  font-size:40px;
}
#spinner {
  animation-name:spin;
  animation-duration:03s;
  animation-iteration-count:infinite;
  animation-timing-function:linear;
 }
 @keyframes spin {
   from {
     transform:rotateY(0deg);
   } to {
     transform:rotateY(360deg);
   }
 }
```

```html
<p id="spinner">Hello, world!</p>
```

What would've been the difference if I would've included all of the `animation` parts in the `p` address where I made the text bigger and centered, or used a class such as `p.main` instead of an `id` called `spinner`? Is there a difference, or is it just preference?

`<p>Thanks!</p>`

Comment: Google **css specificity** and read up on it. This is total basic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's see them one by one:

1. *Using Element name*:
   If you use element as a css selector, you are targeting all the elements with the TagName
   *example*: `p{color: red;}` will make every `p` element's color red.
2. *Using class name with element*:
   Classes can be used for to target more than one element and you narrow down the targets by specifying it for any element.
   *example*: `p.class-name{color: red;}` will only apply for elements having that class name and not all the elements.
3. *Using id's*:
   ID's are unique and has to be precisely, you can target any element which has same ID. It should have one-one mapping so that it means, **no duplicate ids**.
   *example*: `p#some-id{color: red;}` only applies styles for element which has that id.

I hope it made few points clear.